# how to create a user interface that a user can signup and login using django 

Tags: python, django, user-interface, authentication

i love gae(google app engine),because it is easy to create a user interface for user login and signup,

but now , my boss want me to create a site use django ,

so the first is to create a site that someone can be login ,

which is the esaist way to create a user interface ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

User authentication in Django is fully documented [online](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/). The user interface itself is, AFAICT, your problem; I don't know if Django provides one out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

Django auth also provide generic views for login/logout etc. You can use build-in templates or expand it.

See in documentation for generic views: django.contrib.auth.views.login, django.contrib.auth.views.logout